# highcharts - how to position labels over pie charts

Tags: label, highcharts

I'm currently working with highcharts to generate a chart that has several pie charts inside. So basically a data set that has 3 or 4 series, each with their own name and data.  The charts render perfectly, and now I would like to place the series name above each pie in the chart.  The only way I can see to do this is with the label property.  The issue that I'm having is that the series are positioned within the chart with percentages.  A series looks like:

```
series: [
    {
        name: 'series name', 
        data: [25, 25, 50],
        center: ['33%']
    }
]
```

So now I want to apply a label to that series, but I'm having issues deriving what the "style" property should be set to.  using the series center (which I was hoping would position the label directly over the series pie) doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I am not entirely following what you are saying w/the "style" property.  Can you please create a sample jsfiddle?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment malonso.  So here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uJcTZ/681/  

Notice there are two pies, and I'd like to place a label over each pie, though I'm having trouble figuring out how to position the label properly so it's centered over each pie.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?